# React Router Redux - Infinite loop when redirecting from IndexRoute

Tags: reactjs, react-router, infinite-loop, react-router-redux

My routes look like:

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={SEOModuleComponent} onEnter={(nextState, replace) => { replace({ pathName: 'getStarted' }); }} onChange={() => {}} />
        <Route path="getStarted" component={GetStartedView} onChange={() => {}} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app-container')
);
```

When I load the application - it enters an infinite loop constantly trying to redirect to `'getStarted'`

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [`<IndexRedirect>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-redirects) component?

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRedirect to="/getStarted" />
    <Route path="getStarted" component={GetStartedView} onChange={() => {}} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: Because the `onEnter` logic in my actual application isn't as simple as the one provided in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was this:

`(nextState, replace) => { replace({ pathName: 'getStarted' }); }`

Because `"pathName"` wasn't `"pathname"` (lowercase) - the internal workings of react-router's history module were defaulting the redirecting to `"/"` which was the current path, creating the loop.

Issue opened here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4545